# Unable to filter DataFrame using Window function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to use a logical expression based on a window-function to detect duplicate records:

```
df
.where(count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"col1",$"col2"))>lit(1))
.show
```

this gives in Spark 2.1.1:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Aggregate
```

on the other hand, it works if i assign the result of the window-function to a new column and then filter that column:

```
df
.withColumn("count", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"col1",$"col2"))
.where($"count">lit(1)).drop($"count")
.show
```

I wonder how I can write this without using an temporary column?

Comment: I experienced the same problem also when counting with a condition as follows : 
```count(when(lower('type) === "A", true).otherwise(false))```
I had to add a column before which checks if ```lower('type) === "A"``` before applying my window function.

Answer (score 4):

I guess window functions cannot be used within the filter. You have to create an additional column and filter this one.

What you could do is to draw the window function into the select.

```
df.select(col("1"), col("2"), lag(col("2"), 1).over(window).alias("2_lag"))).filter(col("2_lag")==col("2"))
```

Then you have it in one statement.

Comment: I'm also seeing this in Spark 2.1.1. Getting error like, `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: row_number() windowspecdefinition(input[22, string, true], input[1, string, false], input[18, bigint, true] ASC NULLS FIRST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. Unfortunately, have to temporarily add a column, use filter/where, & then remove it.

Comment: that's what I've already posted in my question, this does not add any value