# In Spark Window functions, Why we need to use drop() at the end

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark window functions. I am implementing few examples to learn more about it. Take a look at below example. It's using drop() with withColumn(). I searched a lot on spark docs as well but couldn't able to understand its significance.

```
//Get the top record in each subject with the highest fee
val wSpec = Window.partitionBy($"Subject").orderBy($"Fee".desc)
val dfTop = input.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(wSpec)).where($"rn"===1).drop("rn") //Note: 'input' has my data 
dfTop.show()
```

Can someone explain the significance of drop()? What if I do not use drop()?

Thanks.

Comment: couldn't you try it yourself and observe it?

Comment: Yes, I will do it soon. Just wanted to know about the internals of drop. Thanks.

Comment: the question is why the temporary column `rn` is needed in the first place, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560166/unable-to-filter-dataframe-using-window-function-in-spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why we need to use drop() at the end

We don't. We do it to remove temporary objects, which no longer carries useful information.

> What if I do not use drop()?

You'll have one more column, full of ones, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

drop() is used to drop the column(s) which you don't want any more further, nothing much significance.

You can see it yourself simply by:

```
//Commenting drop()
val dfTop = input.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(wSpec)).where($"rn"===1) //.drop("rn") //Note: 'input' has my data 
dfTop.show()

dfTop.drop("rn").show()
//"rn" column is gone
```